# C# using system.io not woking in my class but works in main

Tags: c#, class, .net, using-directives

I am working on an issue I do not remember ever having before.
I am using VS2012 C#

When i add using `System.IO`; to my main program everything works fine, however when I add it to my class file it will not let me use all of the methods.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace FoxySearch
{    
    class FoxySearch
    {
         File.    <<<<----- here i want to add File.Exists("Blablalba")
    }
}
```

For some reason it wont let me add it. As soon as I add the period the intellisense closes and shows no options.When I then type it out myself it shows red and says,

`System.IO.File.Exists(string)` is a method but is used like a type

Comment: You can't write it in the class definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't really given enough code to say for sure, but it sounds like you're probably trying to write "normal code" directly in a class declaration, instead of in a method or property declaration.

Classes can only include declarations - method declarations, field declarations etc. You can't write:

```
class Foo
{
    int i = 10; 
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

etc. The first line is valid as it's a variable declaration - the second isn't, as it's just a method call. If you move the code into a method, then it's fine:

```
class Foo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        int i = 10; 
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Additionally, I'd suggest that you revisit your naming - using the same name for a class and a namespace is a [bad idea](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx).

Comment: @user1208410 Don't blame yourself that strong))) But accept the answer, if this is the case

Answer (score 1):

You need to put it inside a function or sub, property and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the code in a method, for example:

```
class FoxySearch
{
   public bool DoesFileExist(string filePath)
   {
       return File.Exists(filePath);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u have written in class, u cant write there. & also file.Exists() returns boolean value. u have to write something like this:

```
boolean a= File.Exists("bla");
```

Answer (score 0):

You use File.Exists() in class not in method it is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must add Reference to assembly in your project.